# Error with Azure Synapse HTTP linked service

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm attempting to create an HTTP linked service from the Anonymous website, but my Synapse Analytics does not support it. My Synapse isn't letting me create a pipeline to retrieve data from the HTTP website. Several of the websites I tried didn't work. Kindly address this problem. I have a difficulty.
for example this URL: https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees
and about the Access Control I am added in Azure Center for SAP Solutions service role, Contributor and User Access Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use REST connector to connect to API if HTTP linked service throws error.
- In order to create HTTP linked service in Azure Synapse pipeline without any error, follow the below steps.
- Click on **Manage** icon. Select Linked Services. Click **+New**.
  [image]

-Select Http from the linked service and give the base URL and authentication type. Test connection once and click create.

[image]

- Then create a new HTTP dataset of JSON type. Give the linked service created in above step.
- Use the above dataset as source dataset in copy activity and create the sink dataset of your requirement and execute the pipeline.
- If this HTTP connector is throwing error and not letting you to retrieve data, you can use **rest connector** to connect that public API.